# React.js create multiple tables from array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I have searched for a solution to my problem but nothing worked probably because of my lack of understanding.

I am trying to work with React.js to create tables of dynamic length.

I call an API in my project with the [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library that returns an array of JSON objects, We dont know the size of the returned array, but for each JSON object within the array I need to create a table and add its data. Here is an example of the API call return.

```
[

  {
        "feedbackID": 12,
        "posterID": "John",
        "comment": "shortcomment"
    },
    {
        "feedbackID": 23,
        "posterID": "billy",
        "comment": "long comment"
  }
]
```

So with this return I will have to create 2 tables, one under the other as follows:

```
| Feedback ID | 12           |
| Poster ID   | John         |
| Comment     | shortcomment |

| Feedback ID | 23           |
| Poster ID   | billy        |
| Comment     | long comment |
```

Here is my code so far:

```
   export class ViewFeedback extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      feedback: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var id = this.props.match.params.id;

    // this returns the JSON array like shown above
    getfeedback(id).then((response) => {


     this.setState({feedback:response})

    })


  }
```

I have no clue at all how to make the tables, I tried the `createElement` and also `Grid` But I did it so wrong it wouldn't even compile the code.

Comment: you will need some css to handle the looks.

Comment: I dont care about the css right now I just want the tables for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
renderTable = () => {
    return this.state.feedback.map(value => {
        return (
            <table>
            <tr>   
                <td>Feedback ID</td>
                <td>{value.feedbackID}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>   
                <td>Poster ID</td>
                <td>{value.posterID}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>   
                <td>Comment</td>
                <td>{value.comment}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        )
    })
}

render () {
    return <div>{this.renderTable()}</div>;
}
```

Render method is mainly a view, so moving the logic to a separate method is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
{this.state.feedback.map(item => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Feedback ID</td>
          <td>{item.feedbackID}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Poster ID</td>
          <td>{item.posterID}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Comment</td>
          <td>{item.comment}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  )
})}
```

Use this in your render method

Comment: how do I add a horizontal rule between each table element? I tried added `<hr/>` after `</table>` but I get an error

Comment: @FBSTSUG I guess you need to use styling.

Comment: isnt everything inside the return statement html code though?

Comment: @FBSTSUG It is JSX - an HTML-like syntax, which is compiled to Javascript.

Comment: ah okay, so how would I add styling? Sorry for the terrible noob questions